# jquery load remote html page

Tags: jquery, get, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I whant to load remote html page and then parse it. There are bunch of such examples but could anybody explain why I receive this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://html.comsci.us/examples/blank.html.
>   Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

when I try to load this html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript"
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $.get('http://html.comsci.us/examples/blank.html', function(data) {
           alert('Load was performed.');
        }); 
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: XMLHttpRequest can't cross domain due to security issues.

Comment: @semsorock, suggestions for future questions: no need for "thank you notes", up-vote/accept answers instead. Try to format code so there is no horizontal scroll (preferably provide small enough samples so there is no vertical scroll either).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a script on your own server that requests that page, and you call that script using your ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

The security restriction you are hitting is called "same origin policy" or "cross-domain access".

Ways to work around:

- make query server side or with client application
- if both sites agree on access you can use [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), running code on other site
- JSONP if other site supports it